# RxJs Timer called only once instead of calling every second

Tags: angular, rxjs

Below is my code:

```
this.callActiveListSubscription = timer(0,1000).pipe(switchMap(() => this.realtimeSupervisorHeatMapService.getLiveCallList())).subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log('inside get live call list subscription',data);

        let fetchRequired = data.fetchRequired;
        this.recent_data = data;

        var listOfStrem = data.stream;
        var list = data.list_Of_contacts.filter(function (el) {
                return el != null;
        });
        if (list.length == 0) {


                // Set SelectedCallKey as None and Active Calls to 0
                this.allCallsData = [];
                this.agentCallList = [];
                this.filteredCallList = [];
                this.activeCallCount = 0;
                this.selectedCallData = null;


        } else {
                // set the amount of active calls
                console.log(this.selectedBusinessUnit)
                if(this.selectedBusinessUnit !== 'All'){

                 this.activeCallCount = list.filter(item=>item.business_unit === this.selectedBusinessUnit).length;
                } else {
                        this.activeCallCount = list.length;
                }

        }

        this.agentCallList = []
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if (list[i]) {
                        var agentName = list[i].agent_name;
                        var agtId = list[i].agentId;
                        var streamStartTime = list[i].streamStartTime;
                        var slackDMUrl = list[i].agentSlackDMUrl;
                        slackDMUrl = slackDMUrl === "NA" ? "#" : slackDMUrl;
                        var name = list[i].contact;
                        let phrase_count = list[i].phrases_count;
                        let business_unit = list[i].business_unit
                        let item = { name, agent_name: agentName, agentId: agtId, streamStartTime, slackDMUrl, phrase_count: phrase_count, business_unit }

                        let index = this.agentCallList.findIndex((element: any) => element.name === item.name)
                        if (index === -1) {
                                this.agentCallList.push(item);
                        } else {
                                this.agentCallList[index] = item;
                        }
                        this.agentCallList.sort((a,b)=>b.phrase_count - a.phrase_count);


                        if (i == list.length - 1) {

                                this.changeBusinessUnitDropdown();
                        } else {
                                // console.log("wait")
                        }
                }

        }
})
```

it is inside ngOnInit() and executing only once.

I am expecting it to execute every second as mentioned inside timer. I also used mergeMap instead but no luck. Any help would be appreciated. I have used interval in place of timer as well but still it is not working.

Comment: What is the `getLiveCallList()` method returning?

Comment: @JB17 it returns observables: public getLiveCallList() {
    return this.createObservable('streamArray');
  } private createObservable(eventName: string){
    return fromEvent(this.socket, eventName);
  }

Comment: @AayushMohta: The point of the question was "Is `getLiveCallList()` actually being called and is it returning anything useful.

Comment: @possum, yes it is returning meaningful data in the format: {stream: Array(16), list_Of_contacts: Array(16)}

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `timer` you can just use the `fromEvent` directly, just make sure you unsubscribe it when the web socket is closed! I think you need two streams one for refreshing the data using the timer and another to listen to websocket events.

I could not find an event for `streamArray` so I used `message` event and sharing an example using rxjs `fromEvent` to listen to web socket.

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { of, from, fromEvent, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { map, share, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const socket = new WebSocket('wss://socketsbay.com/wss/v2/1/demo/');
const createObservable = (eventName: string) => {
  return fromEvent(socket, eventName);
};
const getLiveCallList = () => {
  return createObservable('message');
};
getLiveCallList().subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log(data);
});
socket.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
  console.log('open');
  socket.send('Hello Server!');
});
socket.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ws-chat-dpc9se?file=index.ts)